Are there notable Western politicians who endorse the idea that Ukraine can last until Russia runs out of tanks?
That Russia will run out of tanks in 3 years tops [at the current rates of attrition and production/refurbishment] is an idea that's found in some Western sources, be they journalists or think tanks. Ibid about artillery gun barrels, but fewer predictions there. (FWTW, even a Chinese newspaper seems to think that--sans a concrete time frame though, and their motivation [to talk about it] is different.) Personally, I haven't heard of Western politicians talking about this at all. So, are there some Western politicians who explicitly endorse this as a viable strategy for Ukraine and its Western allies?

I don't believe I've ever heard a Western politician (or any other, for that matter) give a particular date that they believe Ukraine "can last until", and frankly I don't know how reliable such an estimate would be anyway.

Vote to close because there's an endless supply of journalists and those may entertain all kind of ideas. The assumption is that politicians do not have to react to every fringe idea.

@alamar: well, if it's fringe, you could explain in a frame challenge answer why that's the case.

It's a war of attrition, so wearing down the other side is the general idea, even if tanks specifically may or may not be part of that.

Beyond a few years, the existing stock of late-cold-war era equipment like tanks or planes will matter less than it once did. Due to advances in cheap military technology. More broadly, the "running out of X" concept is a remnant of the initial Western strategy, which was to rely on the sanctions programme. The fatal flaw in that theory of victory became apparent when Blinken went to China, where he had to ask the world's largest exporter to implement his strategy for him. As it happened, he forgot his previous words and deeds with respect to China, but they did not.

Tanks don't seem to be that amazingly useful on this battlefield in practice.  They seem so far to be used as close support fire platforms, rather than as doctrinal WW2 deep penetration facilitators.  Drones, APCs to protect infantry, artillery, long range precision missiles... lots of things seem more important.  If Russia runs out of tanks they'll just gradually use them less.  What is true is I don't see how Russia is going to quickly rebound from their losses after the war in Ukraine, whichever way that ends.  They just don't seem to have the capacity left for large production.

Russia is probably the country that has most of tanks in the world (or among the tops). Moreover, it is one of the main tank producers and relies on its own production. So the central claim needs to be fleshed out a bit more, to make the question self-contained.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, what is the basis for thinking that Russia doesn't have the capacity left for production? There is massive flab in liberal capitalist economies due to many levels of rent extraction and inefficient use of cheap, oppressed labour. Russia must also still have a significant number of people who remember how to organise a command economy. And they are allies with, not enemies of, the main industrial powerhouse of the world. Why would they fall over under these conditions?

@Steve Have you ever looked at Russian production numbers before this war?  They talk up a big game, but their production numbers are usually very low.  Take the fearsome Armata.  How many have been made in 5-10 year?  20?  30?  The SU-57?  32?  Just an amazing amount of their stuff was designed and built during the Cold War and the rest are prestige low-numbers runs, unless they export it.  They seem to concentrate a lot of their actual efforts into nukes, which isn't that stupid a bet in the least, but only has narrow use cases.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, surely production since the war, and what level it can reach as time progresses, is the relevant question?

If Russian tank supplies fall too much they will reduce the use of tanks. They don't actually need a lot of tanks for a purely defensive war, although it might hinder advances. You can't just extrapolate the loss rate of tanks from the early stages of the war.

@StuartF: yes, but that means they'll attack less than now. FWTW, DW couldn't help delve into this too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xiN9RJkdyk

I think that the real argument, widely advanced, is that Ukraine can hold out until the war ends.
This doesn't necessarily require every last Russian tank or artillery battery to be destroyed, any more than it requires every last Russian soldier to be killed. It simply requires Ukraine to have enough might militarily to not be overrun until the war is concluded in some fashion, on terms that are mutually tolerable (perhaps not even truly ending the war, along the lines of the end of the Korean War).
There are lots of ways that the war could end. Putin could give up. Putin could be replaced by a successor who gives up. Ukraine could reclaim enough territory taken by Russia to declare victory and stop trying to reclaim more territory. The Russian occupied territories could be recognized as separate countries that are neither Russian nor Ukrainian. There could be a ceasefire at whatever lines there are between Russian forces and Ukrainian forces at the time. Ukraine could cause enough damage within Russia that ending that could make Russia decide to enter into some kind of treaty. This list is not exhaustive.
A parallel idea, less widely and more quietly argued, is that every Russian tank that Ukraine destroys is a tank that isn't available for conventional warfare with NATO. Attrition of Russian military resources benefits every potential military adversary of Russia until those military resources can be replenished. From NATO's point of view, even severe Ukrainian losses that cause it to cede much more territory, could be beneficial to NATO, if Russian territorial gains cause Russia to lose a lot of its military capacity to make war with NATO countries in the process.

Germany in WWII also hold out until the war ended. These are related things: any war continue until one side give up. Ceasefires last as long as loosing side needs to gather forces for retaliation.

Yeah, while not about tanks, you're right about the general idea: "“Our message to Russia is that if they think they can outlast Ukraine in this war, they’re mistaken,” the official said, adding, “we are now effectively mobilizing our defense industrial capacity in order to get air defense interceptors that are rolling off the line straight to Ukraine, which will provide them with sufficient quantities to be able to defend against Russian air missile attacks for the foreseeable future.”" https://edition.cnn.com/2024/06/20/politics/ukraine-us-air-defense-capabilities

The linked article seens to have a singular aim:

All Johnson has to do is bring to a vote an overwhelmingly popular bill that would send $60 billion in aid to Ukraine.

Conversely, all of the arguments the article is making are the bullet points in an advertising booklet devised to get the prospective customer to buy. As this transaction has now taken place, the arguments lose their purpose. Nobody is going to seriously fact check them to determine their validity: after all, this is not a military science paper but essentially a paid ad campaign.
So in essense, the answer is yes: the politicians have endorsed this idea by voting this bill in.
To rehash, you do not waste your time taking apart claims listed in the avertising material: you either buy the product or you ignore it. We know this one was sold.

Meh, that's a somewhat correct observation for one of the articles--the one which predicts only 1-year supply for Russia, which is probably overly optimistic. The other one, which says 3 years, isn't of that nature.

This question is about politicians' reactions and not about fact checking the number of Russian tanks. Politicans can obviously endorse the ideas that are implausible, or ignore ideas that are the opposite.

But couldn't it also be that politicians had something else in mind when voting for the bill. This answer seems to assume there are only two options left when there may be more.

Of course. No amount of bullet points in a summer house ad will make you book it if you're not interested in spending time outdoors.

In accordance with Reuters, International Institute for Strategic Studies (IISS) is saying this. It is a global think tank with a focus on international security, political risk, and military conflict. The IISS provides policy recommendations to governments, international institutions, businesses, and the media, so they potentially could be called "politicians".
IISS says that while Russia lost 1,120 tanks in 2023, they managed to put 1,000 to 1,500 more as replacement, roughly breaking even. However from these only about 200 are newly built.

Not my DV, but this is just summarizing one of the pieces linked in the Q (the more conservative one, in terms of estimates).

Russia has lots of tanks:
(image source)

If we take 2020 data provided by Forbes, it is 12,950 out of 73,000 tanks in the world. The US is distant second with 6,333, whereas the total NATO strength (according to this source, but one could add numbers) is 11,309:

In 2024, the combined number of ground combat vehicles among NATO allies was around 872,500, with the majority of these being armored vehicles. A further 11,309 units were main battle tanks.

In other words, Russian does not have shortage of tanks... in terms of raw numbers. One could argue that the main Russian tank fleet dates back to the Soviet times or at least to the Soviet models - like T-72. But one could also question whether this drawback matters, when the tanks are employed on a large scale - does Ukraine have enough modern weapons to deploy vis-à-vis the Russian tanks? Or, perhaps, beyond a few modern systems it was supplied, it is mainly the same old Soviet fleet - either inherited from Soviet times or supplied by eastern European NATO members (who are getting in exchange more modern weapons.)
To summarize: Russia will not run out of tanks. But one could ask a more nuanced question of whether qualitative superiority of the weapons provided to Ukraine by NATO neutralizes Russian numerical superiority.

Your image disagrees with your text, placing North Korea second with 6k, and the US third with 5k.

@JoelHarmon indeed, the text refers to the table in the Forbes article, which disagrees with the image.I think Forbes is more reliable - or uses better criteria for counting.

This answer is extremely low effort propaganda. Completely ignores losses. They've lost ~3,000 already, with replacements coming mostly from those 12K stocks, which include every rusty one stored anywhere visible from a satellite.

@againstverylongusernames since the moderators deleted my comment, but not your insult: 1) I brought up the Russian sheer numerical superiority in the comments s few days ago, suggesting to ask a more meaningful question - to no avail. This is as far as low effort goes.

@againstverylongusernames I clearly say in the answer that quantitative superiority might be offset by qualitative edge. This can be seen by comparing Russian vs. Ukrainian losses - such comparisons are indeed rare - most outlets engage in obvious propaganda citing only the losses of one side. Naturally, I did find some useful, though inconclusive information... by given the insult and downvotes why bother to write it up.

you failed to mention how many tanks does Russia need to dismantle and cannibalize to make one working tank. And this is a very well-known issue to anyone who keeps track on this war. Without mentioning this, your numbers in this picture mean nothing at all. Useless information completely. :)
